# Show that $A$ is a simple group.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

The question is as follows:

Let $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ be the group of all permutation of $\mathbb{N}$. Let $F$ be the subset of $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ consisting of all permutations that fix all but a finite number of points. Let $A\leq F$ be the set of members of $F$ which can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions. Show that $A$ is a simple group.

I would assume that this proof is similar to proving why the alternating group is simple....but am a little stuck on how to go about proving this.

Comment: It is the exact same proof. Show a nontrivial normal subgroup must contain a $3$-cycle, conclude it must contain all $3$-cycles, deduce it must contain all even permutations of finite support. Conclude it is the whole group.

Comment: $F$ is the subgroup generated by finite cycles. Prove that the conjugate of any cycle is a cycle of the same length. Then characterize $A$ in terms of cycle lengths.